# Not as many review options on MSO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues

When looking at the options for reviewing on this site, there are only 3 options, *Suggested Edits, Close Votes,*  and  *Reopen Votes*:

[image: MSO]

Yet when looking at Stack Overflow, you can see that there are 6 options, First Posts, Late Answers, *Low Quality Posts, Suggested Edits, Close Votes,* and *Reopen Votes*:

[image: SO]

Is Meta Stack Overflow designed to be like this, or is this a bug?

Comment: Yes, it is. Not a bug.

Comment: We don't need all the different queues for a meta site, nor is there the VTC-overflow issue. Any activity gets to the front page, and the total activity itself is low enough that not much will slip by.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The First Posts and Late Answers queues do not exist on any meta sites. [This is documented in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues).

Comment: Okay, the only problem I could see is with low quality posts, where someone could ask a question or post an answer which is meaningless, or an answer which should be a question. I guess regular Close Votes would work here, though.

Comment: You mean, all site meta sites? Because it's for sure on central meta.